# how to enlist the module of any exe attached to debugger

Tags: internet-explorer, debugging, windbg, mshtml

I'm actually debugging the IE and want to enlist all the module. My preference is all function contain in MSHTML.dll , but I'm not able to do that.

Things done by me as follow:-

I've attached debugger to IE and then typed the following command

**x *!**

and I got list of pdb files but no mshtml.dll

I'll really appreciate any help or guidance all you can give.

Comment: Guys I'm still not able to see mshtml not listed over there. My scenario is this: i've one web page saved. I want to open that web page with debugger and I want to breakpoint when that webpage is calling Mshtml.dll. Can any one help me how to do that. I'm new to debugging and don't have much of idea to implement it. Can someone enlighten this thought??

Answer (score 2):

Modules are dlls/exe files and to list them you should rather use lm command. For instance to check if the mshtml.dll is loaded with valid symbols issue:

```
lmmv mshtml
```

If no symbol files were found you will need to get them. For example to get symbols fom ms public servers run:

```
.symfix
.reload
```

Finally to list all symbols included the mshtml use:

```
x mshtml!*
```